# Editing menu items on the fly in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a menu item called "Inbox" on a menu called "dealer-menu". I want to change "Inbox" to "Inbox (1)" or "Inbox (2)" depending on the number of messages the user has in his inbox. How do I change the value ON THE FLY. I.e. on every page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
$dealerMenu = menu_navigation_links('menu-dealer-menu');
$menu = theme('links', $dealerMenu);
print str_replace("Inbox", "Inbox (".get_number_of_messages_in_inbox().")", $menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call hook_menu_link_alter then you can set `$item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;` on each menu item - you will need to edit the menu item for this hook to be called and the alter permission set to true.

Once this has been set then hook_translated_menu_link_alter will be called before each menu item is rendered allowing you to change the menu item title.

Example code would be:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
    $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;
}

function MY_MODULE_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {
    if($item['mlid']==89) {
        $item['title'] .= ' ('.get_number_of_messages_in_inbox().')';
    }
}
```

The only limitation of this is that hook_menu_link_alter will mark every link as alterable which is not necessarily desirable (adverse effect on performance) - some additional checks on the $item here would mean you are only marking them menu items you want as alterable.